# How to make a fetch request to TinyURL?

Tags: javascript, reactjs, typescript, fetch-api

I am trying to make a fetch request specifically a post request to tinyURL to shorten a URL generated on my site. here is the tinyURL API

Currently, I am writing my code like this but it doesn't appear to be returning the short URL.

> the word tinyurl seems to be banned within links so all links
> containing the word tinyurl have been replaced with "SHORT"

Here is the tinyURL API https://SHORT.com/app/dev

```
import * as React from 'react'

interface tinyURlProps {   url: string } export const useTinyURL = ({ url }: tinyURlProps) => {   React.useEffect(() => {
    const apiURL = 'https://api.SHORT.com/create'
    const data = JSON.stringify({ url: url, domain: 'tiny.one' })

    const options = {
      method: 'POST',
      body: data,
      headers: {
        Authorization:
          'Bearer xxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxx',
        Accept: 'application/json',
        'Content-Type': 'application/json',
      },
    } as RequestInit

    fetch(apiURL, options)
      .then((response) => console.log(response))
      .then((error) => console.error(error))

    console.log('TinyUrl ran')   }, [url]) 
}
```

Comment: Is this an old version of [your other question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/66991344/how-to-make-a-fetch-request-with-tinyurl-api)?  If so, please delete this one.  if not, please edit one of the questions so as to distinguish it clearly from the other one.

Comment: The two questions are practically the same, and asked only 5 minutes apart?  Why?

Comment: `it doesn't appear to be returning the short url` so what is it doing instead?

Comment: My mistake I didn't think this version posted it returned me to the code and message I had typed with and error, I'll delete the other

Comment: @IanKemp this is the response I get back https://imgur.com/VK4ISDg

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The snippet below seems to work

```js
const qs = selector => document.querySelector(selector);
let body = {
  url: `https://stackoverflow.com/questions/66991259/how-to-make-a-fetch-request-to-tinyurl`,
  domain: `tiny.one`
}

fetch(`https://api.tinyurl.com/create`, {
    method: `POST`,
    headers: {
      accept: `application/json`,
      authorization: `Bearer 2nLQGpsuegHP8l8J0Uq1TsVkCzP3un3T23uQ5YovVf5lvvGOucGmFOYRVj6L`,
      'content-type': `application/json`,
    },
    body: JSON.stringify(body)
  })
  .then(response => {
    if (response.status != 200) throw `There was a problem with the fetch operation. Status Code: ${response.status}`;
    return response.json()
  })
  .then(data => {
    qs(`#output>pre`).innerText = JSON.stringify(data, null, 3);
    qs(`#link`).href = data.data.tiny_url;
    qs(`#link`).innerText = data.data.tiny_url;
  })
  .catch(error => console.error(error));
```

```css
body {
  font-family: calibri;
}
```

```html
<p><a id="link" /></p>
<span id="output"><pre/></span>
```

Comment: Do you think it could be to do with me using '' instead of ``?

Comment: what the use of bearer in that tinyurl api call anyway... i just didn't get it @Steve...

Comment: http bearer authentication as described in the OpenAPI specification